# Problema obteniendo usuario logueado con Gam

Tags: genexus

Estoy implementando gam en mi aplicacion con genexus, pero al tratar de obtener el usuario de logueo no lo esta trayendo. Este es el codigo que estoy usando. Usuario es la transaccion donde se alojan los usuarios de la aplicación, pero tengo dudas si solo con crearlo en gam es suficiente?.... Agradezco su colaboración.
[image: Codigo para obtener usuario logueo]

Answer (score 1):

Dayana,
El problema creo que esta en el llamado a la función "Format" ya que en el string no le estas poniendo los "placeholders" (%1, %2) para reemplazar por los valores &UserGUID y &Today.

Debería ser algo así:

```
Format("Get &UserGUID do inicio :> %1 - %2", &UserGUID, &Today)
```

Revisa la [documentación de Genexus sobre la función Format](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8406,Format%20function)

Prueba arreglar eso primero.